# Proof of Spin-statistics theorem

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spin-statistics

Is this proof of spin-statistics theorem correct?

http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/classes/2008f.homeworks/spinstat.pdf

This proof is probably a simplified version of Weinberg's proof. 
What is the difference?

What is the physical meaning of $J^{+}$ and $J^{-}$ non-hermitian operators?

I'm especially interested in the beginnig of proof of second lemma. How to get this:
\begin{eqnarray}
F_{AB}(-p^{\mu}) = F_{AB}(p^{\mu})\times (-1)^{2j_{A}^{+}} (-1)^{2j_{B}^{+}} \\ \nonumber
H_{AB}(-p^{\mu}) = H_{AB}(p^{\mu})\times (-1)^{2j_{A}^{+}} (-1)^{2j_{B}^{+}}
\end{eqnarray}

Also why under CPT field transform as
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_{A}(x)\rightarrow \phi_{A}^{\dagger}(-x) \times (-1)^{2J_{A}^{-}} \\ \nonumber
\phi_{A}^{\dagger}(x) \rightarrow \phi_{A}(-x) \times (-1)^{2J_{A}^{+}}
\end{eqnarray}
conjugation is from charge reversal, - from space inversion and time reversal.
What about $(-1)^{2J_{A}^{-}}$?

Where can I find similar proofs?

Comment: "Is this proof correct" isn't a conceptual question.  Do you have a question about a particular step in the paper?