# Spin-Statistics Theorem - Proof

Tags: spin-statistics

Is this proof of spin-statistics theorem correct?

http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/classes/2008f.homeworks/spinstat.pdf

This proof is probably a simplified version of Weinberg's proof. 
What is the difference?

What is the physical meaning of $J^{+}$ and $J^{-}$ non-hermitian operators?

I'm especially interested in the beginnig of proof of second lemma. How to get this:
\begin{eqnarray}
F_{AB}(-p^{\mu}) = F_{AB}(p^{\mu})\times (-1)^{2j_{A}^{+}} (-1)^{2j_{B}^{+}} \\ \nonumber
H_{AB}(-p^{\mu}) = H_{AB}(p^{\mu})\times (-1)^{2j_{A}^{+}} (-1)^{2j_{B}^{+}}
\end{eqnarray}

Also why under CPT field transform as
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_{A}(x)\rightarrow \phi_{A}^{\dagger}(-x) \times (-1)^{2J_{A}^{-}} \\ \nonumber
\phi_{A}^{\dagger}(x) \rightarrow \phi_{A}(-x) \times (-1)^{2J_{A}^{+}}
\end{eqnarray}
conjugation is from charge reversal, - from space inversion and time reversal.
What about $(-1)^{2J_{A}^{-}}$?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66220/proof-of-spin-statistics-theorem similar question by OP

Comment: @Nivalth actually it is exactly the same question. In a case like this it would be much better if you flag it as a duplicate (instead of, or in addition to, posting a comment).

Comment: weisskreuz, please don't repost a question that has already been asked. But we do encourage you to edit your original posting to make it more appropriate for the site, and it can be reopened at that time.